# Formula for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{(n+1)-k}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, summation

I have solved a counting problem and I obtained the sum 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{(n+1)-k}{k}.$$

However, this is unsatisfactory to me because I would like an explicit formula. Does anyone know if this is, or is similar, to a famous counting identity? I cannot find it anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you put $n=2$, your sum becomes $$ \binom 30+\binom 21 + \binom 12 $$ , but I don't think $\binom 12$ is defined.

Comment: @WW1 $\displaystyle{{1 \choose 2} = 0}$.

Comment: Generally the sums of the kind $\sum\binom{n-k}{k}$ represent a similar number to the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It is possibile to prove that $$\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-k}{k}=F_{n+1}
 $$ by induction, where $F_{n}
 $ is the $n-$th [Fibonacci number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html). In particular the inductive step is $$\begin{align}\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n+1-k}{k}=
  & \sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-k}{k}+\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-k}{k-1}
 \\ =
 & \sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-k}{k}+0+\sum_{k\geq1}\dbinom{n-1-k+1}{k-1}
 \\ =
 &\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-k}{k}+\sum_{k\geq0}\dbinom{n-1-k}{k}
  \\ =
 &F_{n+1}+F_{n}
  \\ =
  & \color{red}{F_{n+2}}.
 \end{align}$$

Comment: How do you demonstrate that the base cases hold? What I mean is how do you deal with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$?

Comment: @Sarah If $n=0$ you have that all addends are $0$, if $n=1$ we have $\dbinom{1}{0}=1$ and the other addends are all $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{a_{n} \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n + 1 - k \choose k}\,,\quad
\mbox{Note that}\ a_{0} = 1\ \mbox{and}\ a_{1} = 2}$.

---

\begin{align}
a_{n} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n + 1 - k \choose k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n - k \choose k} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{n - k \choose k - 1} =
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n - k \choose k} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{n - k - 1 \choose k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{{n - n \choose n} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{n - k \choose k}} +
\bracks{{n - \bracks{n - 1} - 1 \choose n - 1} +
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2}{n - 1 - k \choose k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\delta_{n0} + \delta_{n1} + a_{n - 1} + a_{n - 2}
\end{align}
Then,
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{a_{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1} 
\\
\ds{a_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{2} 
\\
\ds{a_{n}} & \ds{=} & \ds{a_{n - 1}\ +\ a_{n - 2}\,,\quad n \geq 2} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
These relations show that
\begin{align}
a_{n} & =
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n + 1 - k \choose k}} =
F_{n + 2} =
\color{#f00}{{\pars{1 + \root{5}}^{n + 2} - \pars{1 - \root{5}}^{n + 2} \over
2^{n + 2}\root{5}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{F_{n}}$ is a [Fibonacci Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html).

Answer (score 0):

*I do not think that this is an answer since based on observation.*

I generated a table of $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{(n+1)-k}{k}$$ and starting form $n=1$, obtained $$2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584,
4181, 6765, 10946, 17711$$ Looking at $OEIS$, I found sequence $A000045$ which seems to have been extensively worked.

From the link it seems that the simplest closed form formula is 
$$S_n=\frac{
   \left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{n+2}-\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{n+2}\right)}{2^{n+2}\sqrt{
   5}}=\text{Round}\left[\frac{\phi ^{n+2}}{\sqrt{5}}\right]$$